# itertools accumulate to build a recursive list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools, accumulate

I want to build a list from a seed in such a way:
`seed, seed*weight - seed*weight**2`, and so on, where the previous number is the seed for the next.

so with `seed` of `.5` and `weight` of `3` we would get

`.5, -4, 24.0` and so on

This is what I thought would work:

```
from itertools import accumulate, repeat 

relationship = lambda seed, weight: seed*weight - seed*weight**2
seed = .5 
weight = 3
inputs = list(repeat(seed,10))
first = [x for x in accumulate(inputs, relationship)]
```

Is the problem that the inputs list creates a list of `.5`s, instead of populating the list forward with numbers that I want?

Comment: So... you're just multiplying the number by -6 (or generally by weight - weight**2) each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `accumulate` call doesn't use the `weight` variable you've declared at all. Rather, it uses the first value from `inputs` as the first `seed` (which is as intended), and all the other values as weights (not what is intended).

You could make it work with a different `inputs` list:

```
inputs = [seed] + [weight]*10
results = list(accumulate(inputs, relationships))
```

But I'm not sure `accumulate` is really the best way to solve this problem. I'd think it would be more natural to solve the problem in another way, such as with an infinite generator function:

```
def gen(seed, weight):
    while True:
        seed = seed * weight - seed * weight**2
        yield seed
```

Since the series is a simple geometric progression (multiplying by `weight - weight**2` each step), you could also write a function to calculate each value from a closed-form equation:

```
def calc(seed, weight, n):
    factor = weight - weight**2
    return seed * factor**(n+1)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, yield was something I was trying to figure out how to use but couldnt quite make that jump.